# Distributing 12 oranges and 1 apple among 3 children

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Determine the number of ways to distribute $12$ indistinguishable
> oranges and $1$ apple among $3$ children so that each children gets at
> least one piece of fruit?

Does having $12$ oranges and $1$ apple different with having $13$ oranges? If not, my answer would be $\binom{12}{2}=66$. But if not could you please explain to me what the difference is?

Regards

Comment: The singular of "children" is "child".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, if there were $13$ oranges, there are $66$ possibilities.

Let's make use of this: We first distribute $13$ oranges, and then we exchange one orange for an apple. There are $66$ ways to distribute the oranges, and $3$ ways to select a child which will exchange an orange for an apple. So in total, there are $$66\cdot 3 = 198$$ possibilities.

Comment: There's no overcounting here, right? A child can get an apple in two ways: as the 'obligatory' first fruit or as one of the remaining fruit.

Comment: @Alex I think it's correct. When the 13 oranges are distributed, all the oranges a child holds are equal, there is no "first fruit" which is distinguished from the others.